# How to fill device storage on Android device

Tags: c#, android, storage

I want to fill device storage on Android device for test purposes. As I have read, there is a way to do this (without "zeroing" disk, which is time consuming):

```
long bigSize = 1L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(rootPath + "/DummyFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    long sizeH = bigSize;
    long sizeL = 1L;

    while (sizeH - sizeL > 1L)
    {
        try
        {
            fileStream.SetLength(sizeH);
            fileStream.WriteByte(0);
            fileStream.Flush();
            Debug.Log("Length  = " + sizeH);
            sizeL = sizeH;
            sizeH = sizeH * 2L;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Catch length  = " + sizeH);
            sizeH = (sizeL + sizeH) / 2L;
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows, this method can really fill hard disk within a second, so you can't write data to it anymore.

But I need to fill disk storage on Android device, preferrably via C# code (Unity3d). I know, that maximum file size on Android is 2GB due to FAT32 filesystem, so I slightly modified my code. I tried to write as many 1GB files, as I can (in my example, free disk space is 48 GB, so I limited number of files by 60):

```
    try
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 60; ++n)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(rootPath + "/DummyFile" + n.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                fileStream.SetLength(bigSize);
                fileStream.WriteByte(0);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
            Debug.Log("Written big file " + n);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException)
    {
    }
```

This method writes all 60 files (1 GB each), and I see all these 60 files in Explorer. But - In disk properties (in Explorer) I see 48 GB free... I can duplicate one of these files through Explorer - and then I see 47 GB free.
I spent all my working day trying to understand, WTF is going on...

Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 7.0

Comment: Where did you see that Android uses a FAT32 filesystem? Android has been using `ext4` since 2010.

Comment: ok, I can't write a file large than 2GB anyway